# display a Site tour training windows on the top of my web page for first time visitors

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, designer

I just finished building an application to extract data from database and display it into the screen and generate some csv files. but I do have a lot of inputs that the user has to filled, and I'm worry that the user won't put the right info in the right place, so my idea was to show a training tutorial on the top of my page when first time user visit the page [(I can extract that data from user cookies and/OR Database)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13739920/site-tour-for-first-time-user-for-all-pages), like the one that facebook or Youtube shows when they make changes to the platform, popups next to the feature, when you close it it opens the next one. If anyone done something similar in the past and have an idea or suggestion how to do it, or what library to use, that will be highly appreciated!

I checked a JS library called [Be Aware](http://notes.xoxco.com/post/36766728425/aware-js-make-your-site-reader-aware) but I would like to check with you guys is there's something else that I need to take a look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like the web-tour plugin you seek: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/12/21/website-tour/

Here's a [demo](http://tympanus.net/Development/WebsiteTour/) of it in action.

Comment: That sounds just right! Thank you, I will go ahead and explore it more. hopefully, I will hear something else do to some comparison.

Comment: The best Answer and very easy to use!! thanks again!!